# bash shell script copy first file with certain extension to current directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory filled with multiple .c source files and I am trying to write a shell script in another directory that will copy the first .c file from the previous directory, compile it, run it, and delete it. Now I understand how to compile, run, and delete the files but I am stumped as to how get only one .c file without knowing its name when there are multiple files with the same extension in the directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a loop, then break out after the first iteration:

```sh
for f in dir/*.c; do
    cp "$f" .
    # compile
    # run
    # delete
    break
done
```

Comment: And if you `shopt -s nullglob` first, the loop will simply be skipped if there are no .c files.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can use arrays:

```
files=(*.c)
echo "compiling ${files[0]}"
compile ${files[0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified how you define "the first", but you can use `set` for this:

```
set -- source_dir/*.c
cp "$1" .
# ...
rm "$1"
```

Comment: It is probably wise to quote `$1` here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you by "first" mean the first file in a sorted list.

A for loop works fine, but you could also do:

```
file=`ls -1 dir/*.c | head -1`
# compile $file && run $file && delete $file
```

Comment: I fully agree with your response and the article you refered to. _However_, for a specific use-case, in a controlled environment, it will still work. Considering the risks is part of the process.